# Azure App Service Access Restrictions with SignalR

Tags: azure, networking, signalr, azure-web-app-service

I've got a Blazor Server asp.net Core app hosted in Azure App Service.  I'm trying to limit access to just my IP address using the "Access Restrictions" under the Networking tab in the Azure portal blade.

This works, however on a page where I have a SignalR connection being set up, I'm getting a 403 due to the IP restriction.

```
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Response status code does not indicate success: 403 (Ip Forbidden).
2020-06-25T12:01:55.897406435Z: [INFO]     at System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode()
2020-06-25T12:01:55.897410435Z: [INFO]     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.HttpConnection.NegotiateAsync(Uri url, HttpClient httpClient, ILogger logger, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2020-06-25T12:01:55.897414535Z: [INFO]     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.HttpConnection.GetNegotiationResponseAsync(Uri uri, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2020-06-25T12:01:55.897418435Z: [INFO]     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.HttpConnection.SelectAndStartTransport(TransferFormat transferFormat, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2020-06-25T12:01:55.897422335Z: [INFO]     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.HttpConnection.StartAsyncCore(TransferFormat transferFormat, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2020-06-25T12:01:55.897432236Z: [INFO]     at System.Threading.Tasks.ForceAsyncAwaiter.GetResult()
2020-06-25T12:01:55.897435936Z: [INFO]     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.HttpConnection.StartAsync(TransferFormat transferFormat, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2020-06-25T12:01:55.897439636Z: [INFO]     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.HttpConnectionFactory.ConnectAsync(EndPoint endPoint, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2020-06-25T12:01:55.897443236Z: [INFO]     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.HttpConnectionFactory.ConnectAsync(EndPoint endPoint, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2020-06-25T12:01:55.897446936Z: [INFO]     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client.HubConnection.StartAsyncCore(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2020-06-25T12:01:55.897450436Z: [INFO]     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client.HubConnection.StartAsyncInner(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2020-06-25T12:01:55.897454036Z: [INFO]     at System.Threading.Tasks.ForceAsyncAwaiter.GetResult()
2020-06-25T12:01:55.897457536Z: [INFO]     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client.HubConnection.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

Which IP is SignalR trying to use and how can I work around this?
(using local SignalR not the Azure SignalR service).

Answer (score 0):

You could check [whatismyipaddress](https://whatismyipaddress.com/) on the machine running local SignalR. Add the public external IP address to the `Access Restrictions` of Azure App service. The public IP address may change regularly.

If you want to access your local SignalR from your Azure App Service privately, you could [integrate your app with an Azure virtual network](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-integrate-with-vnet) and setup a [VPN gateway](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-about-vpngateways) connection between your on-premise network and Azure virtual network. In the scenario, you could whiltelist the local IP address. Refer to [How to Find Your Local and External IP Address](https://lifehacker.com/how-to-find-your-local-and-external-ip-address-5833108).